# Angular HttpClient response is null but network tools show response

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Working on an Angular app that I'm updating from 4.x to 5, and I have a service that calls to the server, but the response comes in as null when the network pane in dev tools shows the expected response.

Here is the service method:

```
public ExportPendingInvoicesReport(data: InvoicePaginationRequest){
    const link = AppSettings.API_REPORTS_EXPORT_PENDING_INVOICES_REPORT;
    const params = this.mapRequestParameters(data);

    console.log(params.keys());

    this.httpClient.get<string>(link, {params}).subscribe((response: any) => {
        DownloadHelper.DownloadFile('PendingInvoices.csv', 'CSV', response._body);
    })
}
```

`mapRequestParameters` returns a valid `HttpParams` object, and the network dev tools shows this as the response: [image: DevTools Response]

But in the console, I'm getting a null value for the `response` object. Why is this happening?

Updated with current code.

Comment: Your response doesn't contain JSON, and response thus can't possibly be an object with a _body property. See overload #3 of https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get for how to get a response body as text.

Comment: that makes sense, but even without the `response._body`, `response` is still null. looking at the docs now. (even when `.get<string>()` is used.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call with the parameter option `{ responseType: 'text' }`.

```
this.httpClient.get(link, {params: params, responseType: 'text'})
```

This ways the response body is not treated as json.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear response. testing this now.

Comment: @ChrisRutherford - i had the wrong overload as you were already passing in the options. Add `responseType` to that. See the updated answer.

Comment: still getting an error stating that type `'"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'`

Comment: @ChrisRutherford - See the code I have above in my answer, don't call the generic version of `get` (so no typecasting). The response you get in the `subscribe` call back is a raw string.

Comment: I think that would do it!